# Using conditional login in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have this code in the `viewDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in my **AppDelegate.m**, where result is simply my **HTTP GET request response**, and my *UITabBarViewController* is manually set(with the pointer) to be the initial view controller.

All I'm trying to do is simply make my LoginHomeViewController the rootViewController on startup if the user is not logged in. What do I need to do to make this happen? Do I need to resign the TabBar's status as rootViewController?

```
if([result isEqualToString: @"log"])
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *ivcTabBar = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarControl"];
    [(UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:ivcTabBar animated:NO completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"It's hitting log");
}

else if([result isEqualToString: @"notlog"])
{
    [(UITabBarController*)self.window resignFirstResponder];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *ivcLoginHome = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginHomeStart"];
    [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:ivcLoginHome animated:NO completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"It's hitting notlog.");
}
```

**bug:** currently it is logging me in even when it hits notlog, and gives me the error in the debugger saying: **Warning: Attempt to present UINavigationController on UITabBarController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

**EDIT:** **Changed "notlog" code**

```
else if([result isEqualToString: @"notlog"])
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *ivcTabBar = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarControl"];
    UIViewController *vcLoginHome = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginHome"];

    [ivcTabBar presentViewController:vcLoginHome animated:NO completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"It's hitting notlog.");
}
```

Comment: can you not present loginController on tabBarController and resign it if the user is already logged in instead of setting rootViewController as loginController?

Comment: The way my storyboard is set up, the UITabBarViewController links to its 4 tab views, and the loginController is completely disconnected from all views. I wish to do this entirely programmatically from the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

Comment: refer the answer being posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present loginViewController on tabBarController

```
if([result isEqualToString: @"notlog"])
{
    [tabBarCOntroller presentViewController:@"Your Login View Controller" animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and resign loginViewController from within, once logged in

Comment: Good idea, I will try this real quick.

Comment: Wait.. no. this is exactly what I'm already trying to do in the code posted above

Comment: No you are not, you are presenting loginViewController on rootViewController which is not tabController.

Comment: Ok. I get what you're saying now. I'm not sure how to write this however but I'm trying to right now

Comment: Alright I just tried the only thing that makes sense to me, I'll add it to the question so you can see it. It didn't work though..

Comment: why are presenting ivcTabBar view controller, instead of adding it to the rootViewController?

Comment: Because I do not know how to instantiate the root view controller programmatically, and I thought that setting the "initial view controller" would set the root view controller for me, am I wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44452/discussion-between-ldindu-and-whitehatprince)